# Authenticating a .NET web service using PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, authentication, soap

I'm working with a .net server solution that provides an authentication web service, along with several other service URLs.  The access process involves an initial call to the authentication service URL, and using an 'Authenticate' soap call, which is supposed to return an access token.  This token is then used to make calls to the other service URLs to retrieve data from the server.

The issue I'm having is that I was provided a username and password for the authentication process, but there's no indication of how the credentials are meant to be sent to the server.  Additionally, I'm trying to access the web service (.net based) using PHP.

So far, I've managed to use wsdl2php to generate classes for the authentication service URL, but the classes don't provide any indication of how the username and password are meant to be sent.

I've tried adding the credentials as soap headers:

```
$headerContent = "<o:UserName xmlns:o=\"$namespace\">
                    <o:UserName>$uname</o:UserName>
                    <o:Password>$pword</o:Password>
                  </o:UserName>";
$headerVar = new SoapVar($headerContent, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'o:ClientCredentials', $headerVar);
$this->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));


try {
    return $this->__soapCall('Authenticate', array());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception( 'Not allowed.', 0, $e);
}
```

...but I receive an 'Access denied' message.  Is there a proper way to pass the credentials to the service in order to successfully authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different authentication flavors - forms, basic, oauth. If you have a way  to login via a browser,  I would suggest running Fiddler to peek at the message traffic.  Fiddler is a middleware tool that sits between the browser and server.  It will give you the packet headers - so you can see the encryption, field formatting and content type. You should then mimic the request.